# How do i convert an ArrayList into a multidimensional Array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

this line of code is throwing me the exception: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5

```
String [][] employeeNamesA = new String [2][index];
for (int i = 0; i<index; i++)employeeNamesA[0][i] = employeeNames.get(i);
```

I am trying to convert a ArrayList into a multidimensional Array.

Comment: If the array size is 5, you have the indexes 0-4 available. 5 is out of bounds. But why do you want to create a multidemensional array, if you already have a list?

Comment: Perhaps `employeeNames` does not have an element at index `i`.

Comment: @jlordo is right. he is going beyond his index.

Comment: because at the end of my program i need to print the items in the `employeeNamesA[i][j]`, [i] being a employee name and [j] being information on the employee. If there is an easier way to accomplishment, I would love to learn as I am still new to Java Programming.I understand that i would be going beyond my index, but how do i correct this?

Comment: @Loadmaster, what do you mean "does not have element at i" ?

Comment: @BradJones: [i] can't be the employee name, as it is a reference to the innner `String[]`. Just write an `Employee` class and override it's `toString()`.

Comment: +1 for "_create an Employee class_".  A class is a **MUCH** better approach than using a multi-dimensional array.  Create a clas that contains a _name_ field and an _information_ field.  Then create an array (or preferably a List) of Employee objects.

Answer (score 3):

Your `employeeNames` list doesn't have `index` amount of elements. It most likely has 5, which means it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when executing `employeeNames.get(i)` for i = 5.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the others have it wrong, you don't have to initialize the inner dimension, you already do it in the first line.

Comment: +1, but you should say `employeeNames` _list_  instead of _array_, as he is acceessing it with `get()`

Comment: True, although it is an `ArrayList` by name. :)

Comment: @Voicu: How do you know? He could be using `LinkedList` or any other `List` implementation ;)

Comment: @Voicu: I should start by reading the title :) Anyhow, to avoid confusion I still think if you edit your answer with my first comment it would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

As jlordo has suggested, you should just create an Employee class.

Here's an example:

```
class Employee {

    String name;
    String info;

    public Employee(String n, String i) {
        name = n;
        info = i;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String s) {
        info = s;
    }
}


List<String> nameList = // populate nameList
List<String> infoList = // populate infoList

List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
    String name = nameList.get(i);
    String info = null;
    if (infoList.size() > i) {
        info = infoList.get(i);
    }
    Employee emp = new Employee(name, info);
    employeeList.add(emp);
}
```

---

Now you have a list of Employee objects rather than a silly multi-dimensional array.

(*Notice we check the size of `infoList` in the loop to avoid an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`*)